# Spaces that can't be embedded in the plane

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, let us write $X \preceq Y$ whenever $X$ embeds in $Y$.

Earlier today, I asked the question:

> *Is this a well-quasi-order on the completely metrizable spaces?*

This was short-sighted, as Tom Goodwillie has pointed out in the comments that the closed surfaces give an easy counterexample.

Since I can't accept Tom's comment as an answer, I'd like to modify the question to make it more interesting (while still being very closely related to the original):

> Is there a finite list $F$ of completely metrizable spaces such that, for any completely metrizable space $X$, $X \preceq \mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if $Y \not\preceq X$ for every $Y \in F$?

An affirmative answer would be something analogous to Wagner's Theorem, but with a more topological flavor.

[Considering this question was part of what led me to ask my other question: if embeddability were a wqo (which it isn't), then the answer to the present question would be yes.]

**Candidate list:** the topological graphs $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$, the sphere $S^2$, and the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ obtained by taking the X-Y plane and a sequence converging to the origin along the Z axis.

[Notice that every closed surface contains one of these.]

---

*The following was a comment to the original question. It is not relevant to the modified question, but I am keeping it to explain the post of Nash-Williams below:*

Embeddability is *not* a well-quasi-order for metric spaces generally. An easy way to get a counterexample is to build one by transfinite recursion: you can find infinitely many subsets of $\mathbb R$ that violate either/both of the conditions listed above. The examples you build will be very far from $G_\delta$, so not completely metrizable.

Completely ultrametrizable spaces *are* well-quasi-ordered by embedability. This follows (with a little bit of work) from a version of the Nash-Williams Tree Theorem (see Theorem 11 [here](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/D.Kuehn/bqofinal.pdf)), together with the fact that every completely ultrametrizable space can be represented as a tree.

Comment: The closed surfaces contradict (1).

Comment: @Tom: You're right! The sum of $n$ tori (for example) does not embed in the sum of $n+1$ tori (or vice versa). I feel like a bit of an idiot for missing such a natural example. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I guess one can make antichains of size continuum, even amongst the Polish spaces: fix an almost-disjoint family of continuum many subsets $A\subset\mathbb{N}$, let $\Gamma_A$ be the sum of surfaces of genus $k$ for $k\in A$. So $A\neq B$ in the family implies $\Gamma_A$ and $\Gamma_B$ do not embed into each other.

Comment: @Joel: Correct. And using that idea, one can also find infinite decreasing chains. Just use $\Gamma_{A_n}$ where $A_0 \supsetneq A_1 \supsetneq A_2 . . . $.

Comment: There is a list of seven forbidden subcomplexes (up to a subdivision) for embedding 2-dimensional complexes into $\mathbb{R}^2$ by Halin and Jung [R. Halin and H. A. Jung. Charakterisierung der Komplexe der Ebene und der 2-Sphäre. Arch. Math., 15:466–469, 1964]. I am not familiar with ultrametrizable spaces, but this list could perhaps provide an answer to your question. It includes, for example, three triangles sharing an edge. If this is ultrametrizable, then your candidate list is perhaps incomplete.

Comment: @MartinTancer: The "ultra" that you're referring to was a typo, and I'm sorry for the confusion. The spaces you're referring to are not ultrametrizable (e.g., because every ultrametrizable space has a basis of clopen sets). I don't read German, but (based on the pictures) the link you shared looks interesting, although I'm not sure it answers my question (because "embeds" and "is a subcomplex of" are very different). By the way, I'll point out that three of the four spaces on my list embed into three triangles that share an edge (all but the sphere).

Comment: I am sorry I did not think about the complexes from the list properly. I agree that all of them are ruled out by your candidate list. I also did not assume that the list would provide a complete solution immediately, but it could rule out some cases. By the way, what about taking $K_5$ (or subdivided $K_5$ for more examples), replacing each vertex with a segment and each edge with a double-sided topologist's sine curve. This one seems neither embeddable nor ruled out by the list. (I hope I do not overlook a trivial problem this time.)

Comment: @MartinTancer: No worries! I started this whole discussion by missing something much more obvious, so I'll be the last to judge you. Your idea about modifying $K_5$ by throwing in some topologist's sine curves seems like a good one. Unless I'm mistaken, you should be able to use that idea to come up with an infinite collection of complete metric spaces, none of which embeds in another, none of which embeds in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and such that if $X$ is any space embedding in two of them, then $X$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This would answer the question negatively. Please do write up an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer to the question is negative. However, it should be noted that I did not work out all details for the following counterexample.

Consider a graph $G$ that is not planar. Replace every vertex of $G$ by a segment and every edge of $G$ by a double-sided topologist's sine curve, obtaining a space $X_G$. Then

1. $X_G$ does not seem embeddable into $\mathbb R^2$.
2. If we only consider $G$'s which are subdivisions of $K_5$, then they do not embed one into another. And it also seems that they cannot be forbidden by a finite list of non-embeddable spaces.

Both claims would require some bit of work to be proved properly.

Answer (score 2):

You get a positive answer if you restrict to compact, locally connected metric spaces.

See
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-planarity-of-compact%2C-locally-connected%2C-metric-Richter-Rooney/70090a524f2509408e5170f814ed1b33654bb585
and references therein.

Comment: Interesting -- thanks very much for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: This is not an answer to the question, but a pointer to the solution of a different problem (due to a misunderstanding on my part)**

I'm not an expert on this, so possibly misunderstood something, but to my mind
your result on ultrametric spaces appears to badly contradict Theorem 4.2 of a paper by Louveau and Rosendal, which says that the quasiordering of embeddability for Polish ultrametric spaces is a universal analytic quasi-order (for Borel reducibility), which implies that it is very far from being wqo.

The paper in question is available here: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~rosendal/PapersWebsite/CompleteAnalytic.pdf

Comment: Their result seems to be for isometric embeddings, whereas I'm just asking about embeddings.

Comment: For the case of Polish ultrametric spaces, you can see a detailed proof of (a strengthening of) my assertion in this paper: http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~carroy/papers/qoforfunctions.pdf.

Comment: Oh, OK, I understand. When I read "embedding of metric spaces" I thought the embedding was isometric.